# How to ensure Windows service process is always running?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have a Windows service that is calling a stored proc over and over (in an infinite loop).

The code looks like this:

```
while(1)
{
   callStoredProc();
   doSomethingWithResults();
}
```

However, how there might be cases where the loop gets stuck with no response, but the service is still technically running.

I imagine there are tools to monitor the health of a service, to let operations teams know to restart it.

But for my scenario this won't help since the service will still be technically running, but it's stuck and can't continue.

What's the best way to ensure this process restarts if this scenario happens?

Would the solution be to use a task scheduler that checks for the heartbeat of this process, and restarts the service if it there's no heartbeat for a period of time? To have another separate thread that monitors the progress of the first process?

Comment: Yes. You need the loop to have a heart beat

Answer (score 2):

Windows services have various [recovery options](http://mdenomy.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/using-the-automatic-recovery-features-of-windows-services/) which takes care of question 1. For question 2, the best bet would be to use a timeout approach whereby if the service takes more than X amount of time to complete it restarts or stops what it's doing (I don't know the nature of your service so can't provide implementation detail).

The heartbeat idea would work as well, however, that just becomes *another* thing to manage/maintain & install.

Comment: If I have a timeout, how do I make the service restart itself automatically with code, without human intervention? Do I still raise an error, and in my recovery options, make the services restart if there's an error?

Comment: @HenleyChiu one option is to fire the code off in a different thread and have a timeout on that (there are different ways of implementing this) and if the timeout expires, force the service to restart.

Comment: how do I force the service to restart though? By throwing an error?